# Help me understanding logic behind limits of recurence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

I was trying to understand how limits of recurence relations are working. 
I have one.

$$a_0 = \dfrac32 ,\ a_{n+1} = \frac{3}{4-a_n} $$

So, from what i know, if this recurence relation has a limit, it have to be bounded and monotonous. 
To check if it's bounded i have to calculate $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{4-x}$$ and it goes to 0, so it's bounded.

Now to check if it's monotonous i have to check if $$a_{n+1} - a_n$$ is monotonous.

$$a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{3}{4-a_n} - a_n = - \frac{(a_n-3)(a_n-1)}{(a_n-4)}$$
This expression is monotonous ( decreasing ) but only starting at x = 5. Is it enough to say that this is monotonous?

If it is. We know that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1} $$

So we calculate it $$L = \frac{3}{4-L}$$ and end up with $$L^2 - 4L + 3 = 0 \rightarrow (L-1)(L-3) = 0$$ We know that the limit of this recurence relation can be 1 or 3. 
On our classes there always were some examples that had only 1 possible limit to choose. In this example we have decreasing sequence and $a_0 = \dfrac32$ then one possible limit is 1.

I was starting to check it... What if $a_0 = \dfrac12$? 
What if $a_0 = 5$ or $a_0 = 2$ it turns out that, no matter what starting value we have, sequence always goes to the same limit ( at least in this example ). Is it true for all recurence relations? You can check using wolframalpha [clicking here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%280%29=3/2,%20g%28n%2b1%29=3/%284-g%28n%29%29)
and just manipulate with starting value. Please help me with this and explain those weird things. I'd be so thankful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some conceptual mistakes right from the beginning.

> So, from what i know, if this recurence relation has a limit, it have to be bounded and monotonous.

No, you have that the wrong way around. Every sequence that is bounded and monotonic has a limit, but there are sequences that have limits *without* being monotonic, such as
$$ 2, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{4}, \frac{7}{8}, \frac{17}{16}, \frac{31}{32}, \frac{65}{64}, \frac{127}{128} $$
(which is generated by the recurrence $x_{n+1}=\frac{3-x}{2}$ and has limit $1$, but alternately increases and decreases).

(The word is "monotonic", not "monotonous", by the way).

> Now to check if it's monotonous i have to check if $a_{n+1}−a_n$ is monotonous.

Um, no, checking whether the sequence is monotonic is not the same as checking whether the sequence of first differences are monotonic.

Instead of trying to concoct a single test for montonoicity, it is better to think of it as asking two questions: Is is increasing? Is it decreasing?

In this case, you should be able to prove that **if** $a_n$ is between $1$ and $3$, **then** $a_{n+1}$ is smaller than $a_n$ and still between $1$ and $3$. So this case will continue holding forever, and the sequence is decreasing (which is one of the ways it can be monotonic). The same proof shows it is bounded.

(Why $1$ and $3$? Because those are the fixed points of the functions you're iterating, and I know from experience that the behavior of iterated functions change near such points -- effectively I have seen *informally* that the limit is probably going to be $1$, and I'm now trying to construct a proof that my hunch is right, not trying to feign stupidity and approach it with no hunches).

If you graph the function $y=\frac{3}{4-x}$ it is possible that the only proof you need here is some handwaving that says "for $1<x<3$ this graph is below the line $y=x$ and the function value is always in $[1,3]$".

Your computation of the fixed points now shows that the only limit that's consistent with being decreasing and staying between $1$ and $3$ is $1$, so $1$ must be the limit.

> I was starting to check it... What if $a_0=1/2$? What if $a_0=5$ or $a_0=2$ it turns out that, no matter what starting value we have, sequence always goes to the same limit ( at least in this example ). Is it true for all recurence relations?

Even in this example, if $a_0=3$, then $a_n=3$ for all $n$, and therefore the limit is $3$. But otherwise, if $a_0\ne 4$ such that you avoid dividing by zero, the sequence does tend to $1$ no matter where you start it. To convince yourself of this you need to prove

- If $a_n<1$ then from that point on the sequence will *increase* monotonically towards $1$ (but never become greater than $1$).
- If $a_n>4$ then the next term in the sequence will be negative, and then we're in the previous case.
- If $3<a_n<4$, then the $a_n$ will get progressively further away from $3$ until you reach one that is larger than $4$, and then we're in the previous case.

There are also functions where you can end up with a sequence that grows without bound (such as $a_{n+1}=a_n^2$ if $a_0>1$), or sequences that stay bounded but don't tend to a limit -- such as $a_{n+1}=4a_n(a_n-1)$ which famously exhibits *chaotic behavior* when $a_0\in(0,1)$.

There are also recurrences that have several different attractive limits, depending on where you start them, such as $a_{n+1}=a_n+\sin a_n$.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for correcting me and nice explaination about those starting values. In fact i have one more doubt about proving monotonoicity. You said that if $1<a_n<3$ then $1<a_{n+1}<a_n<3$, what about if we have 3 fixed points? Which to pick? I'm so confused about it... Sometimes we can do $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$ to prove it's decreasing, right? But sometimes, like in this case, we end up with some fixed points. Please explain what to do, like to 5 years old, confused kid. I'd appreciate it so much.

Comment: @Chris: In general what I'd do is chop the x-axis into intervals with endpoints at each fixed point and whenever the function to iterate has a discontinuity (such as $x=4$ in this case). Then there's some hope (it's not quite a certainty) that we can prove that the function has "similar" behavior within any one of the intervals. So the first one to investigate would be the one that $a_0$ is in.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, sometimes the ratio $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is an easier way to prove motonicity. It depends on the exact function you're investigating which one is easiest -- sometimes there's more than one way that works; at other times only one of them does. And sometimes (hopefully not in homework problems) there's nothing that seems to work at all. The best _general_ advice I can give is try a variety of approaches and hope one of them will work. After some time you may get enough experience to have an idea what to try _first_ depending on how the functions look.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have most of your analysis right. Here is the complete discussion:

The two possible limits are $L=1$ and $L=3$ as you correctly point out.

Secondly, 
$$a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{a_n^2 -4 a_n +3}{4 - a_n}$$

Between the two possible limits the numerator is negative, and outside the two possible limits it is positive. So we can make the following general observations

If $a_n < 1$ then $a_{n+1} > a_n$ (since numerator is $>0$, denominator $>0$)

If $1 < a_n < 3$ then $a_{n+1} <a_n$ (since numerator is $<0$, denominator $>0$)

If $3 < a_n < 4$ then $a_{n+1} > a_n$ (since numerator is $>0$, denominator $>0$)

If $4 < a_n $ then $a_{n+1} < 0$

So if you start to the left of $3$, $a_n \to 1$

If you start between $3$ and $4$, $a_n \to 4$ where the recurrence blows up, or you may go past $4$ in which case you down to next case.

If you start to the right of $4$, next number is less than zero and you back to the first case, i.e. $a_n \to 1$

Comment: You are missing (-) before polynomial. :-) Thanks for your analysis.

Comment: oops! I need coffee badly :-)

Comment: Whoops, i think i need coffee, not you, you just reversed dominator instead of putting (-) in front of whole fraction :-D forgive me.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the behaviour of a sequence defined by $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$ with given $u_0$ sometimes it helps to draw the graphs of $y=x$ and $y=f(x)$ on the same picture. Then it becomes possible to "draw" the sequence $u_n$. For example, when $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $u_0=1/5$ the picture looks like this:

[image: plotting recursive sequence on a graph]

The main trick is that once $u_{n+1}$ is drawn, it is easy to find a point $u_{n+1}$ on the horisontal axis by means of "reflection" using the graph $y=x$. 
There are some more details on this on the page where I have have found this image: http://www.fmaths.com/recursivethinking/lesson.php

By the way, this example also demonstrates that the limit can depend on $u_0$. Namely,
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n=\begin{cases}0, & u_0=0 \\ 1, & u_0\in(0,1], \\ +\infty, & u_0>1\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I agree that drawing a graph is very helpful for this kind of problems. But beware that the function in this drawing is qualitatively different from the one in the question!

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes, it is different, but the same method works (try "plot[x, 3/(4-x), {x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}]" in WolframAlpha and then argue the same way). I have suggested this drawing only because it better explains the method, and it was the only drawing of this kind I found on the web ;)